# Rails: Storing Post ID in Comment Table in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a comment model and I want to store the post.id that I am commenting in the comment table in the db in the post_id section. So far my code for the comment controller is set as

**comment controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    *@comment.micropost_id = Micropost.find(params[:id])*
    @comment.save 
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

`@comment.micropost_id = Micropost.find(params[:id])` This is what I have right now but I am unsure how to connect this to a form inorder to receive the post.id. The form is:

**Form**

```
<div class="CommentField">
<%= form_for @comment, :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "CommentButton b1" %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

A friend of mine told me to add a link to the submit button to connect it to the right route to pick up the post.id but I am unsure of that as well. My route is currently:

**route**

```
  resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
  end

  match "/microposts/:id/comments" => "microposts#comments"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out using nested forms... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

or just use

```
form_for [@post, @comment] do |f|
...
```

You're overcomplicating things in your routes too

```
resources :microposts do
  resources :comments
end
```

is all that you need to get this working (i.e. forget the additional `match` line. Try running `rake routes` to see all the lovely URLs that your nested routes have given you.

In your controller, begin by looking up the Micropost

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
  ..
```

Make sense? There's a lengthy but good intro in the API docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: hmmm I am getting this error atm, `Couldn't find Micropost without an ID` `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#create`

Answer (score 1):

you just need to put a hidden input in your form, like this

```
<%= form_for @comment, :remote => true do |f| %>


<input type="hidden" name="micropost_id" value="<%= params[:id] %>" />


<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "CommentButton b1" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and in the controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.micropost_id = params[:micropost_id]
```

Comment: Isn't that a bad way to handle this, doesn't that leave this vulernable to hack?